Book about two girls with special abilities due to their blood
I have come here as my last resort looking for a book I read long ago. I can’t seem to find it anywhere and everyone I have talked to about it never heard of it so I feel like I am going crazy.
It’s about two girls, one is the daughter of a rich family and the other the daughter of the maid working for that family, that grew up together and have each a special ability. The first one can hear people’s heartbeats and I can’t remember the second’s ability. Their mothers have taught them to hide them and to never speak of them.
One day, they are rushed out of the house by their mothers as a “monster” that is hungry for their blood is running after them. During the car ride, they explain that their blood is rare and related to their abilities and they have tried for years to make sure they protect their daughters. Later in the story, it is revealed tht the monster is the rich girl’s dad and that the mothers have worked tirelessly to hide their daughters in plain sight. But now, almost all the kids similar to them have been preyed on and he learns about what the mothers did. He obviously doesn’t care who they are and is determined to “eat” them. I can’t remeber the end of the story but I would be extremly thankful if anyone has any info to provide me.
I read it long ago so the title or the author are unclear. As for the publication date, i can only say that it must have been minimum 7 years ago, so around 2017 if not before that.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a hardcover, a paperback, or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Hi, thank you for answering. I can’t recall the book art but I know for sure it was a paperback.
